# Knockout observable used in text binding not updating ui

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This has been driving me nuts for hours now. I think I have tried everything on the javascript side. In the javascript side I have this value: **resultItem.standingNo** which is a knockout observable. This one works fine, it updates like it should. I've used subscribers and everything I can think of to see that the value is updated and also tried the same to update other observables to use instead of this one.

What happens. The initial value is rendered in the html when I create the observable. But the html bit never receives the updates. I have tried with and without **.extend({ notify: 'always' })**, I have tried *observable*, *computed* and *pureComputed*, none updates the ui. But all gets the new value. I have other observables in the same class which update fine. But they are not located in the same place in the html.

**resultItem.shortName** just below is not an observable and doesn't need to be updated.

So my question is, is there some limitation with the html that prevents some observables from updating? Because I can't see any problem with my code between the two "...". Where those are there is code that get observable updates with no problems. Any ideas?

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: resultLists, as: 'resultList' } -->
    <!-- ko if: resultList.visible -->

        ...

        <!-- ko foreach: { data: resultList.resultItems, as: 'resultItem', afterRender: $parent.renderedHandler } -->

            <!-- Competitor Info Row Start-->
            <tr class="rowDetail" data-bind="toggleCompetitorDetails: resultItem.competitorSelected">
                <td class="selected-competitor-content" colspan="100%">
                    <div class="selected-competitor-container" >
                        <div class="selected-competitor-image">
                            <div class="img" data-bind="attr: { style: 'background-image: url(' + resultList.getRandomImage() + ');' }"></div>
                            <div class="competitor-dot competitor-star" data-bind="attr: {class: resultItem.isTopCompetitor()}, style: { backgroundColor: resultItem.color.toString(), color: resultItem.color.toString() }"></div>
                        </div>
DOES NOTE UPDATE -->    <div class="selected-competitor-position" data-bind="text: resultItem.standingNo"></div> <-- DOES NOTE UPDATE
                        <div class="selected-competitor-info">
                            <p class="selected-competitor-name" data-bind="text: resultItem.shortName"></p>
                            <p class="selected-competitor-captain" data-bind="text: resultItem.name"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Competitor Info Row End -->

            ...

        <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- /ko --><!-- ResultList visible end -->
<!-- /ko --><!-- ResultLists foreach End -->
```

Comment: could you post your JS ?

Comment: Tough! The calculation of that value is spread out. But I do know that the observable I use gets the value update, its just the html that doesn't realise it.

Comment: Is `resultLists` a KO observable? Do you use any mapping?

Comment: No its not, could that be it? Even though children of `resultLists` are observables and works fine?

Comment: probably not.. it's hard to see without the code. Is it something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/hrpemo2x/

Comment: The only thing that _should_ matter, is that `resultItem.standingNo` is a `ko.observable` and you're setting it using `resultItem.standingNo(newValue)`. (If, like you're saying, everything else renders correctly)